# Why does python executes imported script without invoking

Tags: python

Actually I want to invoke one module in middle of the main script by passing main script output as input for that module, but it is not allowing me to run the main script , it executes the module and raises an error. Any solution?

**Main.py**

```
from pic import get_imagepath #this module i m importing
# after detecting image from webcam i just want to pass it to get_imagepath

get_imagepath(image)
```

**Pic.py**

```
def get_imagepath(image):
    ...
    ...
    return imagepath

rgb_image = load_image(image_path, grayscale=True)



error:
from pic import get_imagepath
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\#########################\facenet\pic.py", line 42, in 
 <module>
rgb_image = load_image(image_path, grayscale=True)
NameError: name 'image_path' is not defined
```

this is the scenario. its directly executing pic script at the time of import and raising error like image_path is not defined. please help me

Comment: You must be invoking fn somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: Can you add the error traceback?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is a bit unclear. What error is thrown? But yes, python runs a module when importing it. You can "prevent" this by using the `if __name__ == "__main__":` syntax.

Comment: I expanded my answer to accomodate your Edit of your Question.

Comment: Either script has a bug.  Pasting the error message as is would get more help.

Answer (score 1):

Python runs modules when it imports them, that is how python is supposed to work. If you have modules that are supposed to be imported, they should not have instructions outside of functions. (Unless of course you have code that is supposed to be executed upon import for which there are legitimate use cases)

The Pythonic way of writing a module that is supposed to be imported, but also to do stuff if it is executed on its own, is the `if main` approach:

You put the code that is supposed to be excuted when the module is executed in a function called main:

```
def main():
    #stuff to de when executed directly
```

And at the end you put:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will execute the main function **only** if the module/script is executed directly (for example via calling `python script.py` or double clicking it) , not if it is imported.

**After Question Edit**

Your edit is an example for what I was explaining, your pic.py:

```
def get_imagepath(image):
    ...
    ...
    return imagepath

rgb_image = load_image(image_path, grayscale=True)
#this gets executed upon import
```

The `rgp_image =...` part gets executed upon import and from the code you posted `image_path` is not defined at this point in any way, which is why it is failing.

Comment: i just tried with what you said but it again showing me the same error. i am a beginner please Bernhard can you explain me detail, i am confusing like anything. please help me out

Comment: What exactly did you try? My answer didn't really tell you how to solve the problem, more why it happened. If you just delete the `rgb_image...` line the error should not occur and you get the image path in your main.py. But you don't save it there or do anything with it, so it's hard to know what it is you are trying to do. Do you want `rpg_image` in your main? Then you need to import the `load_image` function as well and execute it with `image_path` which you get from `get_imagepath(image)` in your main.py.